# Bringing someone's ashes abroad

Tags: legal, airport-security

One of my friends last wishes is to spread her ashes at various places around the world. Consequently,

1. Will I be hassled by security for having someone's ashes, in say, a Ziplock bag?
2. Is the practice of spreading ashes forbidden in any country and have a severe (fine above 1000$ or jail time) penalty attached to it?

Comment: ziplock bag? Extremely disrespectful. Expect security to question you for using that method of transportation even if the act of transporting peoples' ashes is legal (which it seems to be in many countries)...

Comment: The answer to 2. depends on where you want to go. In Germany, the unauthorized handling of ashes of deceased is punishable with up to three years of imprisonment.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the US regulation. http://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/human-remains.html

> There are no requirements for importation into the United States if human remains consist entirely of the following:
>
> human remains that are cremated before entry into the United States

Canada: http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/dm-md/d19/d19-9-3-eng.pdf

> Cremated human remains, because they do not pose a
> quarantine risk, do not require a death certificate. However,
> it is recommended that when transporting the cremated
> remains that the importer should carry a copy of the death
> and cremation certificate and ensure that the remains are in
> a container that can easily be scanned (e.g., cardboard,
> wood or plastic).

Doesn't say anything about the ziploc bag.

Australia: http://customs.gov.au/faq/ClearingCustoms7.asp#Q242

> Cremated remains may be carried by a passenger or they can be sent to Australia via Australia Post, air freight or sea freight.
>
> If you are a passenger and are bringing in cremated remains, you do not need to declare the remains to Customs and Border Protection or DAFF Biosecurity, as they are not a prohibited or controlled importation. Nor do you need a permit or special permission from Customs and Border Protection or DAFF Biosecurity to bring the remains to Australia.

And Australia is pretty strict.

Finally, http://www.evrmemories.com/Cremation-Urn-TSA-transporting-s/188.htm